# When is a vector field on a surface a Lie bracket

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations

On a Riemannian 2 manifold, when is a vector field (possibly defined only on the manifold minus a finite number of points) the Lie bracket of two mutually orthogonal vector fields?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are allowing deleting a finite number of points.  How is this different from a vector field defined on a (possibly noncompact or incomplete) Riemannian manifold.  Are you assuming that the Riemannian metric on the original manifold is complete?  Are you requiring something about the 2 unknown vector fields at the 'missing points'?  Also, why use the word 'mutually'?  It doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: 
I want the metric to be extendable to the entire compact surface. However the vector field may not be with some zeros.

i assume that the metric is complete.

Bracket products of of orthomornmal vector fields are pull backs of the Levi-Cevita connection on the unit circle bundle. The questions asks if there is any global constraint on which vector fields can be such pulls backs.

Comment: @marc:  So you want the two vector fields to be orthonormal, not just orthogonal?